# I WANT TO DRAW Rectangle in Graphical User interface

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I want to draw Rectangle in center of screen with some width and height using swing and Abstract window toolkit in  java. the code is mention below please help me. First I draw a grid layout of some labels and textfields where user can input width and height and when User hit draw button it should draw rectangle with specific value.

This is Main class where Layout is drawn.

```
    package ABC;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Drectangle extends JFrame  implements ActionListener{

        public JTextField Height=new JTextField("100",10);

        public JTextField weidth=new JTextField("800",10);

        public int x=00;

        public int y=00;

        public JButton Draw=new JButton("Draw");

            public Drectangle() {

            super("Programme");

            setSize(900,600);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            JPanel pane=new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

            pane.add(new JLabel("Height of Rectangle :"));

            pane.add(Height);

            pane.add(new JLabel("Weidth of Rectangle : "));

            pane.add(weidth);

            pane.add(Draw);

            Draw.addActionListener(this);

            JPanel pane2=new JPanel();

            pane2.add(pane); 

            setContentPane(pane2);


            DrawRectangles d1=new DrawRectangles(x,y);

            Container content=getContentPane();

            content.add(d1);

            setVisible(true);

        }

        public static void main (String args[]) {

            Drectangle d=new Drectangle();

            d.pack();
        }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JButton buffer=(JButton)(e.getSource());

            if(buffer.getActionCommand().equals("Draw")) {

                x=Integer.parseInt(Height.getText());

                y=Integer.parseInt(weidth.getText());
            }

        }

    }
```

This is subclass which draw a rectangle.

```
package ABC;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DrawRectangles extends JPanel {

    public int X;

    public int Y;

    public DrawRectangles(int x, int y) {

         X=x;

         Y=y;// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) {

        Graphics comp2D=(Graphics2D) comp;

        Dimension ScreenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        int half_Screen_Height=(ScreenSize.height)/2;

        int half_Screen_Width=(ScreenSize.width)/2;

        comp2D.drawRect(half_Screen_Height, half_Screen_Width, X , Y);

        }
}
```

I want to draw rectangle using java swing and java art classes the codes are mention above please anybody help me where I am wrong.Thank you.

Comment: You should tell us where it's wrong / what's not working?

Comment: The Layout is working Fine but when I hit Draw button the rectangle is not drawn.

Comment: Where is your actionPerformed code from the button press?

Comment: It is there can you please look at it now

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that the DrawRectangles has 0,0 default width,height. Call `setPreferredSize` on the DrawRectangles you are creating. You also might want to call `fillRectangle` in your DrawRectangles `paintComponent` method just to make sure that the rectangle is actually getting drawn and that the dimensions of `drawRectangle` are within your DrawRectangle component's size

Comment: Can you please give me the demo of code it will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of all the blank lines when posting code.
2. Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.
3. The ActionListener does nothing. The x/y variables are defined in the "Drectangle" class, so they will have no effect on the painting of the rectangle in the "DrawRectangles" class. If you want to affect the size of the rectangles, then you need to have a method in your "DrawRectangles" class like setSize(width, height). This method would update the x/y instance variables and then invoke repaint(). Then in your ActionListener code you invoke that method with the new parameters.
4. Your "DrawRectangles" class should override the `getPreferreSize()` method to give the preferred size of the component.
5. The code in the paintComponent() method should NOT be using the ToolKit.getScreenSize() method. Your panel does NOT cover the entire screen. It is only part of the frame. Instead you use the methods `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to get the current size of the panel.
6. The logic to center the rectangle in the panel is wrong. In order to center the rectangle you need to know a) the width of the panel and b) the width of the rectangle. Then the formula is: xLocation = (panelWidth - rectangleWidth) / 2. Same basic logic for the height.

Read the section from the Swnig tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html) for a basic example of custom painting to get your started. Start with the working example and customize the code for your requirements. The tutorial code will show you how to better structure you code to follow so you follow Swing conventions.